# Resolution of graphics degrades when I run my flash Game

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, graphics, actionscript

Why does the resolution of the graphics that I use for my flash game degrades when I run the game, though the graphics seems great when it is in the development environment???

Comment: Are you using bitmaps?

Answer (score 4):

Two possible reasons: Either your bitmaps aren't set to allow smoothing and they're being scaled or rotated. To fix that you can simply find them in your library, open their properties and check bitmap smoothing.

Or your flash player is set to low quality. In which case you just need to right click on the stage, go to quality, and change that to high.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am using adobe illustrator for characters. Do I have to make any change there?

Comment: If your images are being imported as vectors then your issue will be the flash player's quality settings.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is in the publishing settings; In Flash, go to File > Publish Settings. Set the JPG Quality to 100.